Java application RAC- aware
Is it necessary from a developer POV to know that application is hosted on RAC oracle database? Do we need to add any additional mechanism for making Java application RAC-aware? Can application maintain database connectivity even when there is a single node failure? Do we need to perform any additional RAC-aware tests on Java application?

No, an application should not care what the underlying database architecture is. RAC will take care of failover on its own; there's no need to code for it in the client. Do, however, make your app reconnect/restart on abnormal termination of its database sessions in case the DBAs are doing a rolling bounce. There are a few performance considerations but until you run into issues I wouldn't be too concerned with that.

Thanks for the info. Does this mean, Restarting the application server is mandatory during the rolling update on the database server. Asking this as we noticed the application server lost connection to the database server during the maintenance on database server. Can't jdbc take care of restoring the db connection even without application server restart?

that's a JDBC question. I can only speak to the database. Whatever the client driver and app, it must be able to reestablish lost connections. A rolling bounce (e.g. perhaps to apply a patch) of the database will terminate all sessions connected to the one instance being worked on at any given time. It's on the client to immediate reestablish the lost connection, which will end up going to a different instance that's up. Even if it wasn't RAC, building fault tolerance and resilience into your app is key to good programming. Assume catastrophic failure of all kinds and code recovery into it.

It depends on what you want.

Do you want zero downtime patching?
Do you need to balance load between nodes?
Does your application want just to re-connect to any surviving node in case of failure?

Here are mine recommendations:

Do NOT use default DB service for connecting, create a dedicated DB service for your app
Use connection pool either HikariCP or UCP
UCP is Oracle's RAC aware load balacing connection pool library. See this project to find an example how to integrate your Hibernate/Spring with UCP
RAC "only" guarantees that database will be up and running, even if one of the cluster nodes is lost. If your app wants to also preserve data from non-committed transactions, you have to either implement re-try mechanism in your app or you have to configure your connection pool to use "JDBC Application Continuity" datasource.

